# What is a "Mogul scale"?

Tags: meaning

Context

*In the 1920s, on the surface, the British Empire seemed as self-confident as ever. Some sense of its swagger is given by the Viceroy's new house in Delhi, A British architect working on a **Mogul scale**.*

Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - Episode 8

Answer (score 2):

I think it refers to the degree of swagger that  was typical of the dynasty who ruled India before the British:

***[Mogul](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mogul) is a variant of Mughal***:

> - A member of the Muslim dynasty founded by Baber that ruled India until 1857.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: +1 But the OP really could have arrived at this themselves. I just wonder how many people bother with looking in a dictionary before they post.

Comment: Is this the source of the term "mogul" for a 39 millimeter size lamp base? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogul_lamp